# Generating a random number but with a twist

Tags: php, random, numbers

I need to generate a random number.

But the twist is that the % of lower numbers should  be greater than the higher.

For example.

rand > 1 to 100

**13**,
**15**,
**12**,
**16**,
87,
**15**,
**27**,
**12**,
**1**,
**12**,
98,
**12**,
53,
**12**,
**14**....

The bold integers will be the ones return from the 1-100 range.

The math should be like so `rand = a number lower than max/2`

Hope you  guys can help.

Ps, How would a matrix come into this ? im not superior at maths :(

---

The abs answer seems to be the one.

```
$up = $down = 0;
while(true)
{
   if(abs((rand()%150)-50) < 50)
   {
      $up++;
   }else
   {
      $down++;
   }
   if( ($up + $down) == 500){ break;}
}

echo $up . '/' . $down;
```

Comment: Exactly what kind of distribution do you want?

Comment: You'll need to decide upon the particular distribution that you want. "The math" as you stated it is is wrong, since not all numbers in your example are lower than max/2 = 100/2 = 50.

Comment: My example is ment to show that 0-100, the bold ints are the ones that will be returned. im not sure what you mean by distribution in this matter?

Comment: Why wouldn't `$one_to_this=100; $rand=mt_rand(1,$one_to_this/2);` suffice?

Comment: Finally, understanding the differences between 1d100, 5d20, and 10d10 pays off.  Well, not really.  Those just vary the bias toward median values, rather than first/second quartile as the OP desires.

Comment: @Robert you might be interested to know that *your* [code review proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") is in the commitment phase. Help get it into beta by showing your support :)

Comment: Absolutely amazing, I had thought this had failed. This is great news, thank you sire for informing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about

```
n = abs((rand()%150)-50)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$x = rand(0,1) ? rand(1,100) : rand(1,50);
```

Simple method: the first rand(0,1) selects between the two cases. Either 1..50 or 1..100 as random range. Since 1,100 already encompases 1,50, the latter range is selected 100% of the time, the former case only in 1 of 2 runs.

If you want a distribution where the highest numer 99 gets selected almost never, but the lower numbers 1..20 pretty frequent, then a simple `rand(1,rand(1,100))` would do.

Comment: This has the same odss i think, in my test case they average at 45-55 eaches. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$rand = (rand() * rand()) / (getrandmax() * getrandmax());
```

This will give you a random number between 0 and 1 with a high probability of falling into the lower end of the range and the probability of a larger number decreasing exponentially. You can then scale this result to any range that you want.